# How to pass boolean expression to variable parameter of QueryOptions of GraphQL package in flutter?

Tags: flutter, variables, types, graphql, boolean-expression

#gql #flutter  Hi everyone, I am using graphQL with flutter and would like to pass boolean expression to my graphQL query.
I am using the QueryOption object type of the graphQL flutter package to pass the query to graphql and to define my query parameters.
The problem I have is that I don't know how to tell flutter that I am passing a boolean expression to the variable parameter of the QueryOption object. Is there a way to do that?

```dart
Future<QueryResult> FilteredQuery(
    final GraphQLClient client,
    final FilterModel filter,
    final bool isAvailable,
 
  ) async {
    final QueryOptions options = QueryOptions(
      document: gql(queryCreationsFiltered),
      variables: <String, dynamic>{

        'condition1': isAvailable== false ? {false}:{is_available: {_eq: true}} 

      }
```

Usually to be able to match the right type of the query variable I pass the associated dart type in flutter!
The idea behind that is to apply conditional filtering.
Any help will be welcomed!
Thanks :slight_smile:

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve my problem.
The syntax to use to express the boolean expression in dart should be the following.

`{"is_available": {"_eq": true}}`  and not `{is_available: {_eq: true}}`

My only remaining question is how to easily pass a boolean expression that evaluates to false `{false}` doesnt' work!